# EasyMock deep stubs

Tags: mocking, mockito, easymock, unitils

I have to mock the following security step using EasyMock or UnitilsMock.  Could you please suggest a way to achieve this?

```
String id = context.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
```

This step is related to security.  So I will not be able to create a Principle object and make a two tier mocking.  I know that mockito handles such stuff easily as follows,

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
SessionContext mockContext;
```

But, I need a similar solution using EasyMock or Unitils Mock.  The complete code, I wish to unit test is given below,

```
@Override
@PermitAll
public List<Employee> findAll() {
   boolean isAdmin = context.isCallerInRole(Roles.ADMIN);
   if (isAdmin) {
      return super.findAll();
   } else {
      String id = context.getCallerPrincipal().getName();
      Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("findEmployeeById");
      query.setParameter("employeeId", id);
      return query.getResultList();
   }
}
```

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can mock the `Principal`, then you can stub `context.getCallerPrincipal()` to return this mock, then stub `mockedPrincipal.getName()` to return whatever you need it to.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  Should I have to change the Class Under test to `Principal principal = context.getCallerPrincipal(); String caller=principal.getName();` then mock the Pricipal in my test and inject it into the Class under test?

Comment: I don't think you need to change the SUT.